# Strange Rails Routes Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the [Rails Guide on routing for nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), I have two models and my routes like so:

```
# media.rb
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :captions, class_name: "Captions", dependent: :destroy
end

# captions.rb
class Captions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media
end

# routes.rb
resources :medias do
   resources :captions
end
```

When I run `rake routes | grep captions` I get the following, which seems incorrect. Some of my actions aren't nested the way I expect them to:

```
   media_captions  GET     /medias/:media_id/captions(.:format)      captions#index
                   POST    /medias/:media_id/captions(.:format)      captions#create
new_media_caption  GET     /medias/:media_id/captions/new(.:format)  captions#new
    edit_captions  GET     /captions/:id/edit(.:format)              captions#edit
         captions  GET     /captions/:id(.:format)                   captions#show
                   PUT     /captions/:id(.:format)                   captions#update
                   DELETE  /captions/:id(.:format)                   captions#destroy
```

As you can see, the `index` and `create` actions are properly nested but the other actions are not. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Is it because your "Captions" class is plural?  You're in for some pain if you're not following conventions.  Your caption class file name should be `caption.rb` and look like so:

```
class Caption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media
end
```

Comment: I renamed it and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: True that!  But I don't think that's what is causing the strange routers.  Rails generates routes whether you have the actions in a controller or not.

Comment: Yes, the controller actions exist. In fact, media used to only have set of captions, but now I am changing the model to be able to have multiple captions. So I figured a simple change from "resource" to "resources" will create the correct routes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it stems from the fact that the plural of "media" is "media".  You can check that in the rails console:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
2.0.0-p0 :002 > pluralize(2, "media")
 => "2 media"
```

So Rails thinks it's a singular resource.

Comment: Hmm, possible. But, I tried changing `resources :medias` to `resources :media` and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try changing it to something simple, like 'birds', just to test the theory.

Answer (score 0):

I think routes are constructed this way to make it explicit that the caption is being edited, regardless as to which medias it belongs to.

Consider a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, where a caption could belong to multiple medias. If you had the following routes:

```
/medias/1/captions/10/edit
/medias/5/captions/10/edit
```

You would still only be editing Caption 10. The routes then become redundant. We can write this simply as

```
/captions/10/edit
```

However, using an `index` action nested under a member route means "show me the captions for *this* media", so that needs to be explicitly stated:

```
/medias/1/captions
```

Or for actions such as `new` or `create`, we're saying "make a caption for this media". Again we need a specific route.

```
/medias/1/captions/new
```

And from the looks of things, you could be running into quite a bit of issues with pluralization. I would consider either adjusting your routes to fit convention, or devise a new standard for nomenclature.

Comment: This seems to make sense to me. However, why does rails force this when the model does not have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. The example in Rails Guide uses `Magazine` and `Ad` and the routes are properly nested. The only difference that my models have is the plural issue.

Comment: @JZ11 `resources` doesn't know anything about your relationships. It just knows to build the nested routes. That's why convention is so important. Not everything in Rails knows about everything else, but if you follow convention, they'll fit together.